# How to display single quote in cobol

Tags: cobol

I want to display these words using display statement  **Company's Policy** But if i use so, it is considering the words as variables. I've tried using

```
DISPLAY "COMPANY'S POLICY"
DISPLAY 'COMPANY\'S POLICY'
```

But none worked. How escape this single quote?

sample code:

```
DFHMDF POS=(1,23),LENGTH=30,            
   INITIAL="company's policy"
   ATTRB=PROT
```

Comment: I agree with @Siva Charan: a single quote inside double quotes should work fine.  Can you post a fragment of your code and the compiler error message that leads you believe that a variable is inferred?

Comment: I was unable to see the error. But i am getting maxcc=12. My program was fine before.

Comment: If you are still having issues, please cut/paste the code and the exact error message, and how you are compiling it (using a separate translation step or called by the compiler).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote escaping works in COBOL as it does in many other languages. Try:

`DISPLAY 'COMPANY''S POLICY'`

Two apostrophes in a row indicate a single literal apostrophe character. Or:

`DISPLAY "COMPANY'S  POLICY"`

Use quotation marks as the outer string delimiter which allows you to use unescaped apostrophes within the literal

Within DFHMDF (strictly speaking this isn't COBOL), you are restricted to using the apostrophe as the literal delimiter. Here you need to resort to using two apostrophes in a row.

```
          DFHMDF POS=(1,23),LENGTH=30,                                X            
                INITIAL='company''s policy',                          X
                ATTRB=PROT
```

Comment: I've tried both. But none of them worked. Second one is not accepted, first is accepted but this is the output: companys policy

Comment: @Pramod do you have a continuation marker in column 71? Are you missing a comma somewhere? See above example (I fixed it up a bit).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this has to work

```
DISPLAY "COMPANY'S POLICY"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise COBOL compilers support mixing of quotes.

Any of these will work:

DISPLAY 'He said, "Hello"'.
DISPLAY "He said, ""Hello""".

DISPLAY "I'm tired".
DISPLAY 'I''m tired'.

The QUOTE/APOST option has to do with the figurative constant QUOTE(S), which can always be used as a backup option.

Answer (score -2):

That looks like a BMS macro call.  You will need to use a double apostrophy.

DISPLAY 'COMPANY''S POLICY'

or

DFHMDF POS=(1,23),LENGTH=30,
   INITIAL='company''s policy'
   ATTRB=PROT

You could also use COBOL figurative constants (if the APOST compiler option is on):

DISPLAY 'COMPANY' QUOTE 'S POLICY'

Comment: The OP is talking about COBOL, and was unfortunately using the BMP assembler code as a "see, this works here".

Comment: Right.  So using BMS pretty much indicates that it is z/OS.  In all cases, for both things, the double apostrophe will quote properly.